# Difference between debugger types

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What is the difference between `native only`, `managed only`, `script only` and `mixed (managed and native)` debugger types? They can be found in a project's properties page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different runtime environments have different debuggers.  You are giving the choice of debugger you want to use to avoid starting one up that you'll never use and thus cutting the overhead.  The debugger types are:

- Managed: suitable for .NET code written in a managed language like C# or VB.NET
- Native: suitable for code generated by the C or C++ compiler
- Mixed: a choice you'll make when you need to debug .NET code that inter-operates with native code, common in C++/CLI projects or when you need to debug a pinvoke problem
- Script: useful to debug scripting code, like Javascript, that runs in a browser
- GPU: used to debug C++ AMP code that runs in a graphics card
- Silverlight: used to debug Silverlight code that runs in a browser
- T-SQL: used to debug stored procedures that run on SQL Server
- Workflow: used to debug WF workflows